# Problemas al disparar funcion con evento click y enter. Vainilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, eventos

Estoy intentando hacer una lista de tareas en javascript y quiero que la funcion principal se dispare cuando se clickea sobre el boton "ADD" o cuando se aprieta enter. Hice el siguiente codigo y no funciona:

```
    window.onload = function () {
    var addBtn = document.querySelector(".add-btn");
    addBtn.addEventListener('click', agregarTarea);

    var inputForm = document.getElementById("taskInput");
    inputForm.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode === 13) {
            // Cancel the default action, if needed
            event.preventDefault();
            // Trigger the button element with a click
            addBtn.click();
      };
    })
}
```

La idea es que se dispare la funcion "agregarTarea" al apretar Enter sin embargo el input se borra y la tarea no se agrega. Cuando se clickea en el boton la tarea se añade sin problemas. Alguna idea para solucionarlo?

Answer (score 0):

Hola espero que te sirva el código, saludos!

```html
<body>
  
<input type="text" name="nombre" id="taskInput"/>
<input type="button" value="enviar" id="add-btn" />
 
<script>
     
    var inputForm = document.getElementById("taskInput");
    var addBtn = document.getElementById("add-btn");
     
 function agregarTarea() {
  console.log(inputForm.value);
 }

    addBtn.addEventListener('click', agregarTarea);

    inputForm.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode === 13) {
            agregarTarea();
       };
 });

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Responder sólo con código se considera de baja calidad. Por favor leer [answer]. Te sugiero que edites tu respuesta y agregues una descripción razonable del porqué tu código puede ser una solución válida al problema. Saludos